# cannot move out of `*handle` which is behind a shared reference move occurs because `*handle` has type

Tags: rust

I want to use `foreach` to wait for thread termination. However, the following error occurs and it is not realized.
Please tell me.

```
cannot move out of `*handle` which is behind a shared reference  move occurs because `*handle` has type `std::thread::JoinHandle<()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

```rust
let mut handles = Vec::new();
handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
   let mut data = snd_rx.recv().unwrap();
   data += 1;
   let _ = rcv_tx.send(data);
}));

handles.iter().for_each(|handle| {
   let _ = handle.join(); // <- Error occurred
});
```

Comment: Replace `iter()` with `into_iter()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already stated in a comment, the solution is to use `into_iter` instead of `iter`. Here's why:

When you call the `.iter()` method, you can iterate over the contents of `handles` and get a shared reference into the vector (that means, if `handles` is of type `Vec<T>`, the argument in the closure is of type `&T`). Therefore, you cannot modify the content of the vector.

But this is exactly what you are doing when assigning `handle` to `_` (which just drops the assigned value immediately), since this assignment is moving the value out of the vector into the local variable. The error message is saying, that that would be okay, if `JoinHandle` was to implement `Copy` (like integers do for example, these values are not moved but copied on assignment), but it does not.

In contrast to that, when calling `into_iter`, you get an iterator, that consumes the vector (the vector moves into the iterator, which is then consumed when iterating over it). On every iteration, you get one element of the vector, but you also take ownership of that value, which is okay, since the vector is invalidated after iteration. As you now have ownership of `handle`, you can move it into `_` and drop the value.

Answer (score -1):

Consume the vector from back to front.

```
struct ThreadPool {
    pool: Vec<JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl ThreadPool {
    pub fn new(size: usize) {
        let mut inst = Self{
            pool: Vec::new(),
        };

        for _ in 0..size {
            inst.pool.push(thread::spawn(move || {
                // do something
            }));
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for ThreadPool {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        while let Some(handle) = self.pool.pop() {
            let _ = handle.join();
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why you'd want to use this instead of the into_iter() is because into_iter() takes ownership of Vec which means that drop() wouldn't compile.

Comment: Why not just use `into_iter()`?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give an example of where into_iter() couldn't be used.